# Disable TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA and TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5 with web.config?

Tags: iis, ssl, iis-7, web-config, iis-7.5

I recently purchased an `SSL certificate` for my `website`. I ran some tests with `sslLabs.com` and it gave a warning about two `ciphers` that are enabled: `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_SHA` and `TLS_RSA_WITH_RC4_128_MD5`. My `website` is on a shared server so I am not sure that they can disable these just for my website. I was wondering if there is any way to disable `ciphers` with the `web.config file` or a similar `file` that stores `server` properties? Thanks in advance! I am on a `Windows Server` using `ColdFusion` if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I disabled the RC4 in the Microsoft Azure Cloud.

Basically I disabled it in my machine (Windows Registry) and then export that piece to a file.

[image: Windows Registry]

Then you attach this file to your project and set the "Copy to Output Directory" to "Copy always".

Create a DisableRc4.cmd command file and attach it to the project as well with the copy always.
Add the following code into it:

```html
@echo off
regedit.exe /s DisableRc4Cipher.reg
EXIT /B 0
```

In the end and in my case, it was just necessary to add it to the ServiceDefinition.csdef
[image: ServiceDefinition.csdef]

Hope it helped after so long time.

Answer (score 0):

Last week there was a blog post update which will disable RC4 cypher by default on cloud services. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/azure-services-ssl-tls-cipher-suite-update-and-removal-of-rc4/

This update should be rolling out this month and if the operating system version is configured as automatic it will be automatically installed on the cloud service(see image below)

Next guest OS: WA-GUEST-OS-4.31_201604-01
Release date: May 2 2016

[Operation system version configuration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z8GTf.png)